# Is it possible to use MacRuby on XCode 3

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, macruby

Is it possible to run MacRuby with XCode 3?

It is not possible for me to upgrade to XCode 4.2 because I am running Snow Leopard and have a machine that will not upgrade to Mountain Lion and Apple has pulled Lion from the App Store. I know you can download XCode 4.2 with a Apple Dev Account ($100 per year) but I am looking for a free solution.

Maybe there is an older version on MacRuby that can be installed with XCode 3? If you know which version, I would be interested if the installation instructions differ from that of XCode 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking [here](https://macruby.macosforge.org/files/) for previous versions of MacRuby.

I want to say that version 0.10 was compatible with Snow Leopard, but I'm not certain.